# Can you put a thumbnail image into a pdf which enlarges when you click on it?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, images, interaction, embed

We would like to insert images into our quote in the form of thumbnails which our clients can then click on to make them full size images. Is this possible?

Comment: Please make an [edit] with examples and show us what you've tried so you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this using buttons. You can set up a button to display an image (or anything a PDF page can be). Using either a bit of JavaScript or Show/Hide field actions, you can display the larger button, which is normally hidden, when the thumbnail button is clicked or the mouse is over the thumbnail. The larger button would then revert to hidden when it is clicked or the mouse moves off the smaller button.

Set up both the thumbnail and larger button to have a layout other than "Label Only" and you should see where you can select a file to use as the source for the icon.

Here's the full thread where I stole this from: https://forums.adobe.com/message/3368380#3368380